# Add multiple boolean columns to dataframe based on parsed text - python

Tags: python, performance, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to build out greater functionality in a dataframe via parsing select columns based on a "splitter" and adding each sub-string as a column header and then marking each row as "True" or not for each new column if the sub string is found in the initial split text.

My problem is the code takes too long to run, and would appreciate some input in any more efficient options.

The dataframe I am working with is ~12,700 rows and ~3,500 columns.

Here is the code:

```
def expand_df_col(df, col_name, splitter):

     series = set(df[col_name].dropna())

     new_columns = set()

     for values in series:
         new_columns = new_columns.union(set(values.split(splitter)))

     df = pd.concat([df,pd.DataFrame(columns=new_columns)], axis=1)

     for row in range(len(df)):
         for text in str(df.loc[row, col_name]).split(splitter):
             if text != "Not applicable":
                 df.loc[row, text] = True

     return df
```

For example:

```
                      Test 1              Test 2  
0             Will this work  Is this even legit  
1         Maybe it will work                nope  
2  It probably will not work                nope
```

Should become:

```
                      Test 1              Test 2   not    It    it  will  \
0             Will this work  Is this even legit   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   
1         Maybe it will work                nope   NaN   NaN  True  True   
2  It probably will not work                nope  True  True   NaN  True   

    Maybe  Will  this  work probably  
0   NaN  True  True  True      NaN  
1  True   NaN   NaN  True      NaN  
2   NaN   NaN   NaN  True     True
```

The response provided by @Ted Petrou almost get's me there but not quite:

```
def expand_df_col_test(df, col_name, splitter):
    df_split = pd.concat((df[col_name], df[col_name].str.split(splitter, expand=True)), axis=1)

    df_melt = pd.melt(df_split, id_vars=col_name, var_name='count')

    df_temp = pd.pivot_table(df_melt, index=col_name, columns='value',      values='count', aggfunc=lambda x: True, fill_value=False)

    df_temp = df_temp.reindex(df.index)

    return df_temp
```

Returns the test df as:

```
value                         It  Maybe   Will     it    not probably   this  \
Test 1                                                                         
Will this work             False  False   True  False  False    False   True   
Maybe it will work         False   True  False   True  False    False  False   
It probably will not work   True  False  False  False   True     True  False   

value                       will  work  
Test 1                                  
Will this work             False  True  
Maybe it will work          True  True  
It probably will not work   True  True
```

As a follow up, I've made the edits. The function works on simple examples, but returns either the original column that was desired to be parsed and expanded (if the code after pd.pivot_table() is present) and returns an empty dataframe if only the pd.pivot_table() portion is done.

I cannot for the life of me figure it out (have spent literally all day tinkering and reading on the various functions involved).

Again I have ~12K rows and 1-3K columns, not sure if / how this is impacting the output.

Current function:

```
def expand_df_col_test(df, col_name, splitter, reindex_col):

    import numpy as np

    replacements = list(pd.Series(df.columns).astype(str) + "_" + col_name)

    df_split = pd.concat((df, df[col_name].astype(str).replace(list(df.columns), replacements, regex=True).str.split(splitter, expand=True)), axis=1)

    df_melt = pd.melt(df_split, id_vars=list(df.columns), var_name='count')

    df_pivot = pd.pivot_table(df_melt, 
                 index=list(df.columns), 
                 columns=df_melt['value'], 
                 values=df_melt['count'], 
                 aggfunc=lambda x: True, 
                 fill_value= np.nan).reset_index(reindex_col).reindex(df[col_name]).reset_index()

    df_pivot.columns.name = ''

    return df_pivot
```

Thought I had found a solution, but was not reindexing correctly.

Now this function works on a subset, but I keep getting a ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

```
def expand_df_col_test(df, col_name, splitter, reindex_col):

import numpy as np

sub_df = pd.concat([df[col_name],df[reindex_col]], axis=1)

replacements = list(pd.Series(df.columns).astype(str) + "_" + col_name)

df_split = pd.concat((sub_df, sub_df[col_name].astype(str).replace(list(df.columns), replacements, regex=True).str.split(splitter, expand=True)), axis=1)
```

## df_split = pd.concat((sub_df, sub_df[col_name].astype(str).str.split(splitter, expand=True)), axis=1)

```
df_melt = pd.melt(df_split, id_vars=list(sub_df.columns), var_name='count')

df_pivot = pd.pivot_table(df_melt, 
                 index=list(sub_df.columns), 
                 columns='value', 
                 values='count', 
                 aggfunc=lambda x: True, 
                 fill_value= np.nan)

print("pivot")
print(df_pivot)
print("NEXT RESET INDEX WITH REINDEX COL")
print(df_pivot.reset_index(reindex_col))
print("NEXT REINDEX")
print(df_pivot.reset_index(reindex_col).reindex(df[col_name]))
print("NEXT RESET INDEX()")
print(df_pivot.reset_index(reindex_col).reindex(df[col_name]).reset_index())


df_pivot = df_pivot.reset_index(reindex_col).reindex(df[col_name]).reset_index()

df_pivot.columns.name = ''

df_final = pd.concat([df,df_pivot.drop([col_name, reindex_col], axis=1)], axis = 1)

return df_final
```

Comment: Do you have an example of the DataFrame and expected output?

Comment: You really need to provide a sample dataframe but something like the following might work: `pd.melt (df[col_name].str.split(splitter, expand=True), id_vars=col_name)`. You can then pivot to get what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it to work, just performed the same methodology on the column of interest and concatenated.

10000x faster, many thanks!

here is the final working solution:

```
def expand_df_col_test(df, col_name, splitter):

    import numpy as np

    sub_df = pd.concat([df[col_name],pd.Series(list(df.index))], axis=1).rename(columns={col_name : col_name, 0:'index'})

    replacements = list(pd.Series(df.columns).astype(str) + "_" + col_name)

    df_split = pd.concat((sub_df, sub_df[col_name].astype(str).replace(list(df.columns), replacements, regex=True).str.split(splitter, expand=True)), axis=1)

    df_melt = pd.melt(df_split, id_vars=list(sub_df.columns), var_name='count')

    df_pivot = pd.pivot_table(df_melt, 
                 index=list(sub_df.columns), 
                 columns='value', 
                 values='count', 
                 aggfunc=lambda x: True, 
                 fill_value= np.nan).reset_index('index').sort('index').reset_index().drop([col_name, 'index'], axis=1)

    df_pivot.columns.name = ''

    df_final = pd.concat([df, df_pivot], axis = 1)

    return df_final
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Updated answer #2

```
df_list = [df]
for col_name in df.columns:
    splitter = ' '
    df_split = pd.concat((df[col_name], df[col_name].str.split(splitter, expand=True)), axis=1)
    df_melt = pd.melt(df_split, id_vars=[col_name], var_name='count')
    df_list.append(pd.pivot_table(df_melt, 
                         index=[col_name], 
                         columns='value', 
                         values='count', 
                         aggfunc=lambda x: True, 
                         fill_value=np.nan).reindex(df[col_name]).reset_index(drop=True))
df_final = pd.concat(df_list, axis=1)

                      Test 1              Test 2    It Maybe  Will    it  \
0             Will this work  Is this even legit   NaN   NaN  True   NaN   
1         Maybe it will work                nope   NaN  True   NaN  True   
2  It probably will not work                nope  True   NaN   NaN   NaN   

    not probably  this  will  work    Is  even legit  nope  this  
0   NaN      NaN  True   NaN  True  True  True  True   NaN  True  
1   NaN      NaN   NaN  True  True   NaN   NaN   NaN  True   NaN  
2  True     True   NaN  True  True   NaN   NaN   NaN  True   NaN
```

### Updated answer

It seems the only difference between this answer and the previous is that you want to keep an additional column `Test 2`. The following will get this done:

```
splitter = ' '
df_split = pd.concat((df, df['Test 1'].str.split(splitter, expand=True)), axis=1)
df_melt = pd.melt(df_split, id_vars=['Test 1', 'Test 2'], var_name='count')
df_pivot = pd.pivot_table(df_melt, 
                     index=['Test 1', 'Test 2'], 
                     columns='value', 
                     values='count', 
                     aggfunc=lambda x: True, 
                     fill_value=np.nan)\
             .reset_index('Test 2')\
             .reindex(df['Test 1'])\
             .reset_index()

df_pivot.columns.name = ''

                      Test 1              Test 2    It Maybe  Will    it  \
0             Will this work  Is this even legit   NaN   NaN  True   NaN   
1         Maybe it will work                nope   NaN  True   NaN  True   
2  It probably will not work                nope  True   NaN   NaN   NaN   

    not probably  this  will  work  
0   NaN      NaN  True   NaN  True  
1   NaN      NaN   NaN  True  True  
2  True     True   NaN  True  True
```

### Old Answer

You need to provide a sample DataFrame with sample results to get a better and faster answer. Here is a shot in the dark. I will first provide a sample DataFrame with some fake data and attempt to provide a solution.

```
# create fake data
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['here is some text', 'some more text', 'finally some different text']})
```

Output of df

```
                          col1
0            here is some text
1               some more text
2  finally some different text
```

Split each value in `col1` by a splitter (which will a single blank space here)

```
col_name = 'col1'
splitter = ' '
df_split = pd.concat((df[col_name], df[col_name].str.split(splitter, expand=True)), axis=1)
```

Output of `df_split`

```
                          col1        0     1          2     3
0            here is some text     here    is       some  text
1               some more text     some  more       text  None
2  finally some different text  finally  some  different  text
```

Put all splits in one column

```
df_melt = pd.melt(df_split, id_vars='col1', var_name='count')
```

Output of `df_melt`

```
                           col1 count      value
0             here is some text     0       here
1                some more text     0       some
2   finally some different text     0    finally
3             here is some text     1         is
4                some more text     1       more
5   finally some different text     1       some
6             here is some text     2       some
7                some more text     2       text
8   finally some different text     2  different
9             here is some text     3       text
10               some more text     3       None
11  finally some different text     3       text
```

Finally, pivot the above DataFrame so the columns are the split words

```
pd.pivot_table(df_melt, index='col1', columns='value', values='count', aggfunc=lambda x: True, fill_value=False)
```

Output

```
value                       different finally   here     is   more  some  text
col1                                                                          
finally some different text      True    True  False  False  False  True  True
here is some text               False   False   True   True  False  True  True
some more text                  False   False  False  False   True  True  True
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, and apologies if the question was not clear enough. 

The example you have provided is close to what I am getting at, but the final result you have provided loses the "col 1" column and the indexing of the original df.

Comment: If this is the original df:

                          col1
0            here is some text
1               some more text
2  finally some different text

Then the final, with " " as the splitter should look like:

                          col1               here             is               some           etc.etc.
0            here is some text      True             True           True  
1               some more text      N/A              N/A           True
2  finally some different text    N/A              N/A             True

Comment: You can fix the ordering very easy with `reindex`. If the final dataframe is stored in `df_final` then the following should work: `df_final.reindex(df.col1)`

Comment: I attempted your solution, but it is not quite what I'm looking. I've provided a more detailed question for better clarity. Truly appreciate the help.

Comment: @wingsoficarus116 I've updated my answer to give you a replica of the dataframe you posted, column order for the splitting words notwithstanding.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I clearly am not understanding how .pivot table is functioning.

I've tried to make the function more general, but when I apply to my large dataframe I get only the original column I asked to parse and expand and an "index" column of all NaNs.

The function seems to work well for the small example, not sure what else would help guide your input. 

I have a variable number of columns initially that I need to keep intact.

Comment: In fact, when I comment out anything after pd.pivot_table() - I just get an empty dataframe back. 

Again I have ~12k rows and ~1-3K columns

Comment: You should be able to generalize this pretty eaily. Write a loop to do the splitting and expanding and pivoting and reordering by each column. The save the results to a list of dataframes. Then concatenate them all together. I'm not at a computer at the moment but try and figure it out yourself. If not I'll get to it later

Answer (score 0):

I would use [CountVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html) here:

```
In [103]: df
Out[103]:
                       Test1               Test2
0             Will this work  Is this even legit
1         Maybe it will work                nope
2  It probably will not work                nope

In [104]: from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
     ...: vectorizer = CountVectorizer(min_df=1, lowercase=False)
     ...: X = vectorizer.fit_transform(df.Test1.fillna(''))
     ...:

In [105]: r = pd.DataFrame(X.toarray(), columns=vectorizer.get_feature_names())

In [106]: r
Out[106]:
   It  Maybe  Will  it  not  probably  this  will  work
0   0      0     1   0    0         0     1     0     1
1   0      1     0   1    0         0     0     1     1
2   1      0     0   0    1         1     0     1     1

In [107]: df.join(r)
Out[107]:
                       Test1               Test2  It  Maybe  Will  it  not  probably  this  will  work
0             Will this work  Is this even legit   0      0     1   0    0         0     1     0     1
1         Maybe it will work                nope   0      1     0   1    0         0     0     1     1
2  It probably will not work                nope   1      0     0   0    1         1     0     1     1
```

or using standard way with the default `lowercase=True` (it will first make all words lower case):

```
In [111]: X = vectorizer.fit_transform(df.Test1.fillna(''))

In [112]: r = pd.DataFrame(X.toarray(), columns=vectorizer.get_feature_names())

In [113]: r
Out[113]:
   it  maybe  not  probably  this  will  work
0   0      0    0         0     1     1     1
1   1      1    0         0     0     1     1
2   1      0    1         1     0     1     1

In [114]: df.join(r)
Out[114]:
                       Test1               Test2  it  maybe  not  probably  this  will  work
0             Will this work  Is this even legit   0      0    0         0     1     1     1
1         Maybe it will work                nope   1      1    0         0     0     1     1
2  It probably will not work                nope   1      0    1         1     0     1     1
```